# ODL fows added in config but not in operational

Tags: opendaylight

All the flows that I add to the config datastote doesn't appear in the operational one if I make a GET. ¿What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the flows you have written to the config store are not programmed
on the switches. The operational is a reflection of the state of the network.

Comment: Yes, I know this, but, ¿What can be the problem here? I have been triying all the sample ODL flows and same problem with all.

Comment: your switch(es) might not even be connected. your switches might be rejecting the flows sent by ODL. you might be programming your flows on a URL for a switch that doesn't exist. check for clues in the karaf.log, or the switches logs, or even you can do a tcpdump on the controller or switch system to see if flows are indeed being sent where you expect them to be sent.